# Error : open Xml file wiht Chrome that contains spcials characters in namespaceURI

Tags: xml, google-chrome, firefox, namespaces, uri

I have an XML file that could have special characters in namespaceURI.

this file is opend without problem using Firefox but it show errors when I use Chrome.
Look at the example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<nexus:customer xmlns:nexus="http://www.nux.io/modèl/carpooling/1.0"  path="/home/test"> 
    <LISTE> 
        <el>Content data</el>
    </LISTE> 
</nexus:customer>
```

Comment: Strange! Chrome is using ISO-8859-1 when reading the file (or just when interpreting the URI)

Comment: On the other hand, RFC 3986 forbids non-ascii characters in the path component of the URI, so you could argue that the `http` uri in the document is malformed.

Comment: Thanks @forty-two for your reply,
But there is no problem when I use url as value of path attribute

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a gray area. From the XML specification's perspective, attributes can have almost any character content except `<` and `&`, but according to the XML Namespace specification, the `xmlns` attribute value is a URI reference, and the path component of URI references are bound to a limited set of ASCII characters and escaped sequences.

For your URI to be truly legal, it should be written as:

```
 http://www.nux.io/mod%C3%A8l/carpooling/1.0
```

where `C3A8` is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character è(U+00E8).

If you paste the URL above into Chrome you'll see that it works, and that Chrome correctly interprets the escape sequence and replaces it with è when displaying it after rendering the resource (same for Firefox).